# Can't import libGDX project into Eclipse.

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, import, libgdx

So i'm trying to start working with libgdx. First error occures during project generation, using libgdx project generator: "Could not determine java version from '9.0.1'.", but it still generates a project. When i'm trying to import it to eclipse, i chose the right path to the project and when i click finish nothing happens. Can someone help me? Thanks.

I'm using newest version of gradle, eclipse, JDK

Comment: Java 9 is really new. You should be sure all the pieces you want to use support Java 9.

Comment: Yup, that was the issue. I'm using now JDK 8 and i works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something in that build environment does not like Java 9. Install Java 8 and point Eclipse at that.